# Is there a way to check in empty directory?

Tags: git

Using git, I am wondering if I can check in empty folder or not?

Comment: Please look at the suggested questions before posting. This is a really popular question.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You cannot commit empty folders in Git.

A common work-around is to add an empty `.gitkeep` file to the folder, and check *that* in, or to simply place a `.gitignore`, ignoring the types of files that will wind up in that folder. Presumably, you want to ignore them, or you'd have something to commit.